# In-Channel Monthly / Annual Subscription issue in Roku / Bright Script

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have gone through all of the documentation stuff and have read about the `roChannelStore` component that can be used for in-channel purchases or subscriptions. I have also found out about the "Fake Server" approach for local development (side-loading) and how it uses the xml files as the server calls instead of actually talking to roku server when we do `store.FakeServer(true)` where `store` is an instance of `roChannelStore`.

## My Scenario

I have an application that shows a video thumbnail and when I click on it, it shows an option to "Play".

## My Requirement

I want to check if the current user is subscribed to the video shown and only then show the "Play" button. I can do this by fetching the subscribed products using `GetPurchases()` function and then checking if the product is inside that collection. Otherwise show two buttons. One for monthly subscription price and the other for annual subscription price that I can use to trigger the Order Placement.

## The Problem

The way I see it, a product can be set as either Consumable, NonConsumable or MonthlySub in that xml file. Is that possible for a single product that I can choose if I want either monthly subscription or annual? How to handle this scenario? I cannot figure out how to allow both monthly and annual subscription types link to one product and then trigger that specific subscription from my code.

The xml file I'm talking about is the "GetCatalog.xml" xml file, provided in the "csfake" folder in the sample project that I downloaded from https://blog.roku.com/developer/2013/06/06/supporting-in-app-purchases-in-your-roku-brightscript-channels/ (download link in the end)

Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not list two versions of the same product, one with a monthly and one with an annual sub? Then show the proper version in context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about this approach too but I had two confusions. First, In the sample GetCatalog.xml file I didn't see an annual subscription product type, only monthly or NonConsumable. For monthly the type was defined as "MonthlySub". Do you know what can I use for yearly subscriptions? Second, can I use the same "code" for two products?

Comment: As far as I have done my research so far. I think there's no other way than creating two versions of it. So I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Re types of subscriptions, see the dev. portal. The fake server xml file is outdated.

More discussion here https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=97065

Comment: That is actually my own post on roku forums that you mentioned and it doesn't have anything to say that the fake server xml is outdated. What's your source?

Comment: :) i know, i am also the one who answered you there. just linked the threads together for posterity. Great job on detailing your question BTW, i +1 you.

Comment: Two things are source for my speculation: the fact that said XML has no annual subscription example - and also my experience with roChannelStore gives me subjective feeling of how "dusty" that corner is (documentation not kept updated).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was you :) considering different names. Thanks for the +1, if you don't ask proper question, you won't get proper answer, simple :) well yeah I have seen that too. The documentation is very dusty for roChannelStore. btw I did find something (don't remember from where) for simulating yearly subscriptions. You can have "YearlySub" in the product type.